# How to sort a 'date' column in a csv to show only spring data for a yearly range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, weather, python-datetime

I am working with a large data set of daily temperature maximums and minimums. I want to look at just the spring daily maximum temperatures from 1971-2000. Here is sample of my data set:

```
Date, TMAX, TMIN
6/1/68,70,51 
6/2/68,76,57
6/3/68,74,55
6/4/68,78,54
6/5/68,76,54
```

....cont'd all the way through 2018

I created a new data set with only the years 1970-2000 by doing this:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1971_2000 = df[ ≤br>
    (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) > 
        pd.to_datetime('1971-01-01')) & 
    (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) < 
        pd.to_datetime('2000-12-31')) 
]
```

But I cant figure out how to only look at March, april, and may TMAX for this subset of years. I've tried whats below. 
But keep getting the error

> TypeError:'getset_descriptor' object is not callable

```
SpringTemps = Valid1971_2000[
    (pd.to_datetime(Valid1971_2000['Date']) > 
        pd.to_datetime(month(3))) & 
    (pd.to_datetime(Valid1971_2000['Date']) <
        pd.to_datetime(month(6)))
]
```

Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to access your months via the [`dt.month` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) of `pandas` datetime objects. Then, you can check that it's either march, april or may by seing if it is 3, 4, or 5:

```
Valid1971_2000.loc[Valid1971_2000.Date.dt.month.isin([3,4,5])]
```

You could also use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) instead of `isin`:

```
Valid1971_2000.loc[Valid1971_2000.Date.dt.month.between(3,5)]
```